# Do the Jews believe that prophet Muhamned is their prophet?

Tags: history, islam

Shalom friends do the Jews believe that prophet Muhamned is their prophet do the Jews follow his teachings also what do the Jews think of prophet Muhamned. Thank you Shalom.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56692/8775 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28825/8775, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33467/among-the-gentiles-why-job-and-bilaam-were-recognized-as-prophets-whereas-muham?s=4|0.5708, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50670/8775.

Comment: Judaism believes God has sent prophets to other nations. Muhammad is not a profit to Jews. I am not knowledgeable enough to inform you how  Jewish authorities view Muhammad in terms of his status as a prophet to Arabians

Comment: The short answer is that we do not believe him to be a Jewish prophet, and we do not follow his teachings. Any time that we seem to follow a teaching must be because he said something that was already found in the Torah. This question is similar to why we do not think Jesus is a Jewish prophet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Jews do not believe that Muhamned is their prophet and do not follow his teachings, whatever they may be. Jews follow the teachings of the Torah which was taught to us by the master of all the Prophets, Moses, our teacher.

One of the most concise sources to understand the Jewish view of Muhamned is from the censored portion of the Mishnah Torah by Rabbi Moshe ben Maimon in Hilchot Melachim, chapter 11 which states:

> And all the doings of Jesus the Nazarene and that of that
>   Ishmaelite who came after him (*meaning Muhamned*) are nothing but to pave the way for
>   the King Messiah and prepare the entire world to worship G-d together,
>   as it says, “For then I will convert the speech of the nations into a clarified language,
>   that they may all call upon the Name of the L-rd, to serve Him with
>   one consent” (Zephania 3:9).
>
> How is this so? The world is now already filled with matters of the
>   Messiah and matters of the Torah and matters of the Commandments.
>   Knowledge of these matters have spread to the distant islands and to
>   the many nations of those with uncircumcised hearts. They discuss
>   these matters and the Commandments of the Torah. Some of them say
>   that these Commandments were once true, but have since been canceled
>   for our times as they were not meant to be observed for all
>   generations. Some of them say that these are secret matters and are
>   not as simple as they would appear, and the *“Messiah”* *(meaning Jesus or Muhamned)* has already come
>   and revealed their secret meanings.
>
> But when **the true King Messiah** will rise and succeed, and he will be
>   lifted up and raised aloft, they all will immediately return *(to the true service of G-d)* and will
>   know that ***their ancestors*** left them an erroneous legacy, and ***their
>   ancestors and prophets*** led them astray.

Comment: I don't see the Rambam you quoted addressing if he's a prophet or not. Maybe he's a prophet who paved the way for the Messiah?

Comment: The language Rambam uses is: "וכשיעמוד המלך המשיח באמת, ויצליח וירום ויינשא--מיד הם כולן חוזרין ויודעים ששקר נחלו אבותיהם, ושנביאיהם ואבותיהם הטעום." That clearly refers to 'their prophets and ancestors'. They believe that these individuals are prophets at the very least.